# cgroupfs-mount fails to start and restrict installationof other packages

Tags: 14.04, package-management, upstart

I'm having a weird issue with `cgroupfs-mount` on a server running Ubuntu 14.04. I don't how this started but now whenever I try to install some new packages, I receive this error:

```
* cgroupfs-mount is managed via upstart, try using service cgroupfs-mount start
invoke-rc.d: initscript cgroupfs-mount, action "start" failed.
```

I tired to search for a possible reason and I found that any manual modification of `/etc/fstab` could alter the service execution so I commented all entries but I'm still receiving this error.
I also receive it when trying to remove the package.

What's wrong?